# Scala 3: Using experimental types

Tags: scala, scala-3

The following scala 3 code following documentation works fine

```
import scala.compiletime.ops.string.*
@main def refinedTypeInAction: Unit = 
  val hello: "hello " + "world" = "hello world"
  println(hello)
```

However, the one below

```
import scala.annotation.experimental
@experimental  
object UseExperimental:      
  def x: scala.compiletime.ops.string.Substring["hamburger", 4, 8] = "urge"
```

throws compile time error as shown below

```
[error] -- [E008] Not Found Error: /Users/viswanath/projects/myproject/src/main/scala/RefinedType.scala:16:38 
[error] 16 |  def x: scala.compiletime.ops.string.Substring["hamburger", 4, 8] = "urge"
[error]    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[error]    |   type Substring is not a member of object scala.compiletime.ops.string
[error] one error found
```

I did refer to https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/experimental-defs.html but I'm struggling to get past the compilation error. Please help!

Comment: This compiles for me in the 3.1.2 and 3.1.3 REPL.

Comment: I used scala 3.1.1 and it didn't work. I upgraded to scala 3.1.3 and now it works. Thanks for your input!